# Telegram Bot - Expandable Menu at the bottom

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

[image]

How do I create a menu like the one at the left-hand side bottom of the Telegram bot? Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Go to botfather, search for your bot and go to edit bot and then update the commands there, now your bot will show the menu

Comment: This is the solution. It worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: It works. This is the official way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation, found out this feature is a product update rolled out by Telegram itself (Presently available only on android devices) and no work is needed by bot developers.